# Can't update Mongoose subdocument property

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Using the following line of code I can update a given Transaction (document), but when I try to update properties of its subdocument, the given value is not persisted.

```
Transaction.findById('55cf89abe148323e5368dcd5').populate('cryptocurrencies')
  .then(function(transaction){
  transaction.status = 'completed'; // this updates the transaction status correctly
  transaction['cryptocurrencies'][0].status = 'ordered'; // this update is not persisted
  return transaction.save()
  .then(function(transaction){
    console.log(transaction['cryptocurrencies'][0].status); // this shows the status as updated, but it's not persisted
  })
})
```

I've also used the line `transaction['cryptocurrencies'][0].markModified('status');` after I update the property to no avail. Can't find anything in the docs: What am I missing?

**Update:** I've  tested this further and found that I have to use the .save() method on both the document and its subdocument. Is there any I can run a method that will save the document with its subdocument properties changed, or do I have to run two operations to save one document each time?

**Update:**

Here is my model code:

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var TransactionSchema = new Schema({
  userId: { type: String, required: true },
  status: { type: String, enum: ['unpaid', 'failed', 'paid', 'ordered', 'received', 'withdrawn', 'completed'] },
  invoice: String,
  saltStatus: String,
  saltTransactionId : Number,
  saltBank: String,
  saltConfirmation: String,
  saltAmount : Number,
  saltDate : String,
  saltResponseCode: String,
  cryptocurrencies: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'CryptoCurrency' }]
});

var CryptoCurrencySchema = new Schema({
  currencyName: String,
  price: Number,
  amount: Number,
  total : Number,
  walletAddress: String,
  dollarsPaid : Number,
  exchangeTransactionId: Number,
  coinTransactionId : String,
  status: { type: String, enum: ['ordered', 'received', 'withdrawn'] }
});

module.exports.Transaction = mongoose.model('Transaction', TransactionSchema);
module.exports.CryptoCurrency = mongoose.model('CryptoCurrency', CryptoCurrencySchema);
```

Comment: Which versions of Node and Mongoose are you using?

Comment: iojs version 3.0.0, mongoose 4.0.6

Comment: Can you update your question to show your schema definitions

Answer (score 1):

From your code example it seems that you are saving the sub-documents as references which means that once you update the sub-document, you only need to call .save() for it and not the parent document as well.

If you are saving your documents as sub-schemas, once updating the sub-document you can call .save() only for the parent document and it will persist the child document as well.

From the docs:

> Sub-documents enjoy all the same features as normal documents. The
>   only difference is that **they are not saved individually, they are
>   saved whenever their top-level parent document is saved.**

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html

Comment: Okay, that sounds about accurate and I should have some time to test that now. Looking at my own model it does seem that it is structured as a reference and not a subschema.